# JS Countdown timer with hours/seconds not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have a countdown timer, which is working perfectly in Chrome, but not in Safari.
I already found similar questions on SO, but could not find the solution for me.

If I remove the hours and seconds from the timestamp, it is also working in Safari, but I need it with hours/minutes.

```js
  function makeTimer() {
     datestamp = "2019-09-25 00:00";
        var endTime = new Date(datestamp);
        // var endTime = new Date("2019-09-25 00:00");
          endTime = (Date.parse(endTime) / 1000);

          var now = new Date();
          now = (Date.parse(now) / 1000);

          var timeLeft = endTime - 7200 - now;

          var days = Math.floor(timeLeft / 86400);
          var hours = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600);
          var hours2 = Math.floor(((timeLeft - (days * 86400)) / 3600) + (days * 24));
          var minutes = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600 )) / 60);
          var seconds = Math.floor((timeLeft - (days * 86400) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)));

          if (hours2 < "0") { hours2 = "00"; minutes = "0"; seconds = "0"; $(".body").addClass("timerOff"); } else if (hours2 < "10") { hours2 = "0" + hours2; }
          if (minutes <= "0") { minutes = "00" } else if (minutes < "10") { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
          if (seconds <= "0") { seconds = "00" } else if (seconds < "10") { seconds = "0" + seconds; }

          $("#hours2").html(hours2);
          $("#minutes").html(minutes);
          $("#seconds").html(seconds);
      }

setInterval(function() { makeTimer(); }, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="hours2"></span>h
<span id="minutes"></span>m
<span id="seconds"></span>s
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gh017jL/3/)

Comment: Check the console in Safari to see what the error is

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm on Safari and not seeing an error actually. Haven't debugged this, but nothing appearing. I do have to say that this code looks a bit more co0mplicated than necessary (`Date.parse(now) / 1000`? Just use `Date.now()` and skip a step that complicates things, then compute using milliseconds since everything works on the basis of milliseconds in JS anyway)...

Comment: @somethinghere I am not the JS pro, just tried my best to get this working :D – I also don't get an error, just see that, that the countdown in Safari is not running. If you could change it to get it running, this would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> A string value representing a date, specified in a format recognized
>   by the Date.parse() method (these formats are IETF-compliant RFC 2822
>   timestamps and also strings in a version of ISO8601).

In short, `datestamp = "2019-09-25 00:00"` is your wrong point. Changing the date to `2019-09-25T00:00:00Z` should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`new Date` constructor with a timestamp is discouraged because its incompatibility across browsers. Quoting [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

Some browsers will try to parse the date even if it's not in a standard format. Safari isn't among those browsers.

To get a compatibility across browsers, consider using [moment](https://momentjs.com/) or parsing the string with a custom function.

### momentJs:

```
moment(datestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
```

### custom function:

```
function parseDate(str) {
   return str.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})/).slice(1, 6);
}
```